# Is there any order for brachot said on seeing natural phenomena simultaenously?

Tags: blessing, natural-phenomenon

You are standing at a distance from a powerful storm. Simultaneously, you see lightning, a tornado and a rainbow. Each of these require a different bracha. Is there any order to which bracha you should say first, second and third?

Possible criteria - Perhaps the order should go by what lasts shortest to longest? Clearly, lightning has the shortest duration of the 3, so maybe that should be first? Between the tornado and the rainbow, it is hard to say which would last longer.

Comment: You can't delay saying on the lightning or you miss your opportunity. Rainbows usually stick around a few seconds at least.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's true, and that was part of what I considered. However, with a tornado on the ground, there's a high likelihood that there will be more lightning strikes, and you could say the bracha on a different strike.

Comment: You still will have forever missed saying it on this strike.